# SublimeText bug in order of execution involving time.sleep in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, sublimetext2

Consider the following python code:

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
print("WOT!")
time.sleep(5)
#... 50 similar lines
time.sleep(5)
```

I run this in Sublime 2 with standart python build.
What would you expect would happen?
The program sleeps for the entire duration of all time.sleep()'s and only then it prints "WOT!". 
So it seems that somehow, all these statements for the thread to sleep are executed before the print statement, but only when running in Sublime Text.
For example if I type the following code:

```
while True:
    print("Hello world!")
    time.sleep(5)
```

the output window in sublime doesn't output anything ever.

Can someone please confirm they are having the same issue and maybe give an idea for resolution?

Comment: Runs good in mine. Can you mention the steps you took to run the script?

Comment: One likely cause of this issue is that the output of the program is buffered, and since Sublime displays the output as it's actually sent to `stdout`, you only get to see the output when it's all done. (or in the second case when it's been running long enough to fill the buffer). If this is the case, something as simple as adding `sys,stdout.flush()` prior to the sleep should fix the problem (or use unbuffered output).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and Solved it
the problem was the {file}.sublime-build that you created in the sublime text they should be like this 
in this case iam using python3.7 and my file name is python3.7.sublime-build
in your sublimetext>Tools>Build System>New Build System

```
{
   "cmd": ["{PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON}/python3.7", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
   "selector": "source.python",
   "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line([0-9]+)
}
```